# How to get decoration text to be right side up instead of upside down

Tags: arrows, decorations

I am drawing arrows in a block diagram and using decorations.text to label them. Arrows going left to right are fine: the labels are upright. But arrows going right to left are appearing upside down.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[graphics, active, tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta, bending, decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (aa) at (0,0) {A};
\node (bb) [right= 5cm of aa] {B};
\draw [-latex] [postaction={
    decoration={text along path, text align=center, raise={1em},
        text={Hello World}}, decorate
        }]
    (aa) to [bend right=45] (bb);
\draw [-latex] [postaction={
    decoration={text along path, text align=center, raise={1em},
        text={Goodbye World}}, decorate}]
    (bb) to [bend right=45] (aa);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How does one get "Goodbye World" to appear right side up? (I know I can use latex- to reverse the arrows, but in a complex drawing I'd prefer to draw the arrows the way flows actually happen in my model.)

Comment: You forgot the most important node: the document around this fragment of code ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can add `reverse path` to the edge options. By the way, I suggest you start using the [`standalone`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/standalone/standalone.pdf) class, which is very handy for typesetting single tikzpictures. It even has the options `tikz` (loads the package) and `preview`. See the link to the manual for more details (class is on page 7).

**Edit:** As A.Ellett rightfully pointed out, `ex` measurement is usually adopted for vertical shifting and `em` for horizontal shifting.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=15pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta, bending, decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (aa) at (0,0) {A};
\node (bb) [right= 5cm of aa] {B};
\draw [-latex] [postaction={
    decoration={text along path, text align=center, raise={1ex},
        text={Hello World}}, decorate
        }]
    (aa) to [bend right=45] (bb);
\draw [-latex] [postaction={
    decoration={text along path, text align=center, raise={-2.5ex},reverse path,
        text={Goodbye World}}, decorate}]
    (bb) to [bend right=45] (aa);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: We posted almost simultaneously.  :-)

Comment: @A.Ellett Ahah yes. I had finished the answer some minutes ago, I was just writing the stuff about the standalone class. I can delete my answer and post that part as a comment if you prefer.

Comment: Doesn't matter to me.  I think the OP wanted the text under the curve.  If you modify your solution to include that I'll delete mine.  I think it's also important to point out the non-standard use of `em` to place things vertically.